# Ubuntu w/ HWE installing wrong driver for GPU

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus

Ubuntu keeps picking the [430 driver](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/146629/en-us) for my GTX 770m card, which is the wrong driver for this card as the newest for my card is [418.88 per NVIDIA](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/149219/en-us). It does list other drivers but those are ALSO incompatible.

I've tried both 18.04.3 and 19.10 versions.

Is there a way to fix this problem? I should also mention it's an Optimus Laptop. The model of the computer is Toshiba Qosmio X75-A7295.

Comment: Please advise the make and model of the laptop. Get the model number from the serial number sticker; any other 'model' number won't help us find the hardware manual. Please then click [edit] and put that into the original question; please don't use Add Comment, but instead use [edit].